# HTML mail signature : code is not applied on windows

Tags: css, windows, email, html-table

I have modified an email signature for the company that i'm working with, everything looked great when i tested it.

The things is that i did code on a mac, and when my client send a mail to a windows user, there is a small part of that signature that does not apply my styles options

Here's my code :

```
<tr>
    <td style="width: 167px; padding: 0px 13px 8px 30px; border:none;" class="">
        <span style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; padding-top: 5px; font-size: 9pt; margin-right: 10px; color: rgb(119, 119, 119); vertical-align: top;" >partner of</span>
        <a href="link" title="brand website link" style="color: rgb(4, 180, 134); text-decoration: none;" class="">
            <img moz-do-not-send="false" width="35%" src="http://www.website.com/wp-content/themes/brand/images/logo-inner@2x.png" alt="Logo brand" style="padding: 10px; border-radius: 5px;  background-color:#153754; border: 0px;" class="">
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This code already works with another image on the top of the signature so i assume it must come from my styling ?

Which is suppose to do this : [right behavior of the style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0RRh.png)

But this is the behavior i get on Windows :[wrong behavior of the style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgbwI.png)

I can't find anything anywhere, so if you have an explanation, i'd be glad to hear it !

Thank you all !

Comment: The only little thing I can see is that the `<img>` tag is not closed properly, it should be `<img />`, but that doesn't usually cause any trouble. You can try that... Any error in the console?

Comment: You need to clarify a few things.  First of all, what is the size of the images, what is the size of the table?  Remember the rules of HTML if not all the elements fit on a line it is permitted to wrap to the next line and you have defined a fixed-width table column which will force the elements to wrap if they are larger in combination.  I don't see the table definition itself in here either so it makes it harder to judge.

Comment: What CSS is applied?  This could affect it as well.  IE is notorious for ignoring styling when it is difficult to comply e.g. conflicting the width and positioning.  Also, fonts can be render different on other platforms especially since you specified fallback fonts so it will choose whatever it can.

Comment: So many Jeremys here

Comment: @Jeremy Well my Real problem  is the img cause it does not take any style, neither my background-color nor my border radius

Comment: what do you mean "on windows"? Different email clients have different limitations as to what they can and cannot render. could this be related?

Comment: @k88lawrence Well i tried on the mail thing of mac, on Gmail, and on outlook everythings works fine on iOS but the two person i tried with was on outlook AND on windows that configuration does not work

Comment: then it's probably the client-- outlook for mac and outlook for windows are not the same and don't support the same properties. see https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/color-background/background-image/ for some information about compatibility-- for example, if you look at `background-color`, it's supported in Outlook for mac but buggy in outlook 2007-2016. i suggest using a service like https://litmus.com/ to preview how your email will look in different clients.

Answer (score 0):

The `background-color` isn't working because you're applying it to the image. Outlook 2007-2016 does not support styling `ALT`. Apply the background color to the actual table cell for the image and it will work.

No image is loading because **YOU POSTED A DUMMY LINK TO AN IMAGE**. If you're going to come here asking for help, **post your actual code**. I took the time to test your code to determine the best way to help you. Don't make us work harder just to help you. That's rude.

Outlook has partial buggy support for Padding:

- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/box-model/padding/

Outlook has partial buggy support for background colors:

- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/color-background/background-color/

My suggestion is to create a table with two cells. Color the one with the image using `bgcolor="#ff0000"` or whatever color you wish. That will give you a reliable background color. Apply your font styles to the image `style` which will change the font for the `ALT` if an image doesn't load. Use `cellpadding` to give yourself the padding you want with Outlook.

Good luck.